# What is the best way to normalize unicode in all z3c.form input fields?

Tags: python, unicode, plone, z3c.form

I'm facing a quite simple problem: the web font we are using on our website does not have the character combination for `a` plus `combining umlaut` (so `ä` in **two** unicode characters), but it does have the `a with umlaut` character.

As we can not really replace the web font, and as suggested by [Mozilla and W3C](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=940944), we should convert those two characters into a single one (fortunately Python already has [unicodeddata.normalize](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize)).

So the question is: how do I make sure that any text input field is normalized? My current approach is using an event handler on creation and edition to go through all text fields and normalize them, but that feels error prone (new content types, new fields...).

Is there something like `collective.dexterityindexer` (as in an adapter that you can create custom converters for specific types of widgets) and make it global (so for all content types)?

Is that ever possible with `z3c.form` (fortunately we are only using z3c.form based forms)?

Comment: I would simply have my custom form base class, which has a helper method normalize() which I would call from my save() / apply(). Are you looking to normalize unicode on z3c.forms you *do not* control, like core Plone forms?

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa, yes, the add/edit forms, I just defined some interfaces, created some content types with the given interfaces and that's all, so I do not have a custom form base class